# Adding CAShapeLayer to UIButton Not Working

Tags: swift, uibutton, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am working on a Swift project and creating a circle around a UIButton, using CAShapeLayer and creating a circular UIBezeir path.The problem is that if I add this CAShapLayer as a sublayer to UIbutton,It does not work. However adding this sublayer on UiView creates the circle.

Below is my code.

```
let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: lockButton.center, radius:
        CGFloat(lockButton.frame.size.width/2), startAngle: CGFloat(startAngle), endAngle: CGFloat(sentAngel), clockwise: true)
    UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()

    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath

    view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 10.0





    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    // Set the animation duration appropriately
    animation.duration = 0.5

    // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1


    // Do a linear animation (i.e. the speed of the animation stays the same)
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

    // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
    // right value when the animation ends.
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 3.0

    // Do the actual animation
    circleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
```

Can anyone suggest me, if we can add CAShapeLayer to UIButton?
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to add a CAShapeLayer to **any** CALayer's sublayers. Making it behave is another question entirely. What are you trying to do? A "circular button" doesn't need any new layers. Masking to bounds is also something I'm not seeing. So give more details of what is and isn't working, maybe I can be of help.

Comment: I am trying to add Circular progress around the button

Comment: Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @SundeepSaluja What does "It does not work" mean for you?

Comment: I mean , it did not add the circle on exact place. It placed the circle away from button. I am sorry, I should have mentioned this in my question.

Comment: Yes, you should have. Please rewrite the question in a way that explains exactly what problem you are having. What result do you want, and what result do you get?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I don't see any change in your question. However, I think you'll find that my answer goes to the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 2):

One very obvious problem with your code is that your `circleLayer` *has no frame*. It's kind of amazing that anything appears at all. You need to set the frame of the `circleLayer` so that it has size and so that it is positioned correctly with respect to its superlayer.

Comment: It might also help you to see code that puts a circular shape layer in a button and works correctly: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p566customThermometer/ch25p840customThermometer/MyCircularProgressButton.swift

Comment: Do I need to provide frame, I am asking this because, I have provided center  and radius to UIBezeirPath.

Comment: This isn't about the path, it's about the layer and where it goes in its superlayer.

Comment: Hey Matt, Setting arc center to CGPoint(0,0) and setting position of circle layer solved the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem you need to remove UIButton **background color** and set it on the default value.